# Difference between 2 Polars dataframes

Tags: python, python-polars

What is the best way to find the differences between 2 Polars dataframes?
The `frame_equal` method tells me if there is a difference, I want to find where is the difference.

Example:

```
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame([
    {'id': 1,'col1': ['a',None],'col2': ['x']},
    {'id': 2,'col1': ['b'],'col2': ['y', None]},
    {'id': 3,'col1': [None],'col2': ['z']}]
)

┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ id  ┆ col1        ┆ col2        │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]   ┆ list[str]   │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", null] ┆ ["x"]       │
│ 2   ┆ ["b"]       ┆ ["y", null] │
│ 3   ┆ [null]      ┆ ["z"]       │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘


df2 = pl.DataFrame([
    {'id': 1,'col1': ['a'],'col2': ['x']},
    {'id': 2,'col1': ['b', None],'col2': ['y', None]},
    {'id': 3,'col1': [None],'col2': ['z']}]
)

┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ id  ┆ col1        ┆ col2        │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]   ┆ list[str]   │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a"]       ┆ ["x"]       │
│ 2   ┆ ["b", null] ┆ ["y", null] │
│ 3   ┆ [null]      ┆ ["z"]       │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

The difference in the example is for id = 1 and id = 2.

I can join the dataframes:

```
df1.join(df2, on='id', suffix='_df2')
┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ id  ┆ col1        ┆ col2        ┆ col1_df2    ┆ col2_df2    │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]   ┆ list[str]   ┆ list[str]   ┆ list[str]   │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", null] ┆ ["x"]       ┆ ["a"]       ┆ ["x"]       │
│ 2   ┆ ["b"]       ┆ ["y", null] ┆ ["b", null] ┆ ["y", null] │
│ 3   ┆ [null]      ┆ ["z"]       ┆ [null]      ┆ ["z"]       │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

**Expected result**

I would like to either:

- add a boolean columns that shows True in the rows with a difference
- filter and only display rows with a difference.

The example has only 2 columns, but there are more columns in the dataframe.

Comment: Would this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73273844/how-to-get-the-difference-sets-of-two-polars-dataframes

Comment: hi @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ, I had checked that answer but it was for a different problem. thank you though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the filter approach

```
(
    df1.join(df2, on='id', suffix='_df2') 
    .filter(pl.any_horizontal(
        pl.col(x).ne_missing(pl.col(f"{x}_df2"))
            for x in df1.columns if x!='id'
        ))
)
```

If you wanted the bool column then you just change the `filter` to `with_columns` and add an alias.

```
(
    df1.join(df2, on='id', suffix='_df2')
    .with_columns(
        has_diff = pl.any_horizontal(
            pl.col(x).ne_missing(pl.col(f"{x}_df2"))
            for x in df1.columns if x!='id'
            )
        )
)
```

This assumes that each df has all the same columns other than 'id'.

Comment: that's exactly it. thanks @Dean MacGregor.
would a pl.struct concatenating all columns also be a good approach?

Comment: I guess it depends how you're determining what a good approach would be.  I don't think it would make it faster.

Comment: IMPORTANT: After [#9053](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/9053), Polars now propagate `null`s in equality. The above code now needs to use `.ne_missing()` instead of `!=` for correctness, or it will not detect a difference between `null` and a value.

Comment: @F.D.Castel thanks for the flag, I updated that, the formatting, `any_horizontal`, and named parameter instead of alias.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `==` to compare frames:

```
>>> df1 == df2
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬───────┬──────┐
│ id   | col1  | col2 │
│ ---  | ---   | ---  │
│ bool | bool  | bool │
╞══════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ true | false | true │
│ true | false | true │
│ true | true  | true │
└──────┴───────┴──────┘
```

Comment: That’s a good one. I didn’t know it was possible. I imagine I should run a sort before to ensure the ordering is the same . Then do a pl.any(~(df1 == df2)) to find the rows with at least one difference